# RichTextBox ClickedLink Value

Tags: vb.net, hyperlink, richtextbox

I have an app that:

1. Opens a .rtf that has hyperlinks to places with in said .rtf
2. Copies contents of .rtf
3. Closes .rtf
4. Pastes contents of .rtf into RichTextBox

I want the user to be able to click the link in the RichTextBox and it take them to the same spot as it would have in the word doc. I have a LinkClicked event handler attempting to get the text value of the hyperlink. Every hyperlink seems to return the same value of "\l". The expectation is that e.LinkText returns 'ACT' or 'PY1' etc. DetectURLs is set to true. Does anyone have experience with this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: If only there was a way that we could get some of the actual RTF data you're using so that we could test it for ourselves.

Comment: Since I'm learning this (and it's why I'm asking in the first place) , perhaps you could help me understand how to acquire that rtf data? Is it from the original rtf file? Could I get it while debugging in Visual Studio?